# what is optimized alternative of using loops

Tags: performance, loops, iteration, coding-style

I need to iterate nearly 200 objects using for loop may increase the response time is there any other way to iterate objects with less time

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling

Answer (score 0):

If

- the time required to process each of those 200 items is already optimal and
- caching results from previous executions of this loop is not an option

you might get a speedup from distributing the work to multiple threads, each iterating over a segment of the list.

To give you more help, you probably need to state your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Don't guess about performance, measure it using a decent profiler.

I bet that the profiler will show the problem to be something you do with the 200 objects in the loop body, and not the loop iteration instructions.

The bare `for` loop itself, using the typical integer loop variable, should take at most a few microseconds for your 200 iterations. So, unless you're doing really high-rate real-time calculations, this doesn't matter.